# Nav Drawer, TabLayout, ViewPager, Hamburger Icon Application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

I am creating a navigation drawer with tabs and viewpager. The hamburger icon is not being displayed on the toolbar and the tabs titles are also not being displayed. I have tried opening one of the tabs from the nav drawer by calling viewpager.setCurrentItem() method. My android support libraries are up to date at the time of posting this question. Please take a look at the code and point out my errors.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout = null;
private NavigationView navigationView = null;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
private int navItemIndex = 0;
private String[] activity_titles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //error occurs here

    getSupportActionBar();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setTitle("Eat Where");
    initWidgets();
    initNavMenu();
    initTabLayout();
    setUpViewPager();

    activity_titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

}

private void setUpViewPager() {
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
}

private void initTabLayout() {
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("HOME"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("FAVORITES"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("NEARBY"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void initNavMenu() {

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.nav_drawer_open,R.string.nav_drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    // This line below does not jump to the requested tab
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(item.getItemId());
                case R.id.nav_favorites:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(item.getItemId());
                case R.id.nav_nearBy:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void initWidgets() {
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dLayout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_menu,menu);
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overflow,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id  = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.menu_settings:

    }

    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Error from logcat is shown below:

```
Process: com.example.joey.eatwhere, PID: 19987
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.joey.eatwhere/com.example.joey.eatwhere.Activities.MainActivity}:
     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
   at com.example.joey.eatwhere.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
   at com.example.joey.eatwhere.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:197)
   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:265)
   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:175)
   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:97)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
   at com.example.joey.eatwhere.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
   at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
   at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:580)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:197) 
   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:265) 
   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:175) 
   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:97) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
   at com.example.joey.eatwhere.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

activity_nain.xml file where the error occurs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:menu="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/dLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.joey.eatwhere.Activities.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/layout_toolbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        menu:tabTextAppearance="@color/colorAccent"
        menu:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"/>

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->
        <!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
        <!--android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>-->

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerFrags"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    menu:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_layout"
    menu:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    android:layout_gravity = "start"/>
```

I understand it's a really long question but I need this for my project. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ask a question with a proper title. Your title doesn't gives any idea about your problem

Comment: Read the question description again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add drawer layout then you must add `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>` as a parent tag in your xml layout and keep `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>` inside it.

---

For more information you can visit, [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html), [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) and [This tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html)